# Number of real solution of Inverse Trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

> The number of real solution of

$\displaystyle \sin^{-1}\bigg(\sum^\infty_{i=1}x^{i+1}-x\sum^\infty_{i=1}\bigg(\frac{x}{2}\bigg)^i\bigg)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\cos^{-1}\bigg(\sum^\infty_{i=1}\bigg(-\frac{x}{2}\bigg)^i-\sum^\infty_{i=1}(-x)^i\bigg)$ lying in $(-1,1)$

(Here $\displaystyle \sin^{-1}\in\bigg[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg]$ and $\displaystyle \cos^{-1}\in[0,\pi])$

What I try : $\displaystyle \sin^{-1}\bigg(\frac{x^2}{1-x}-x\frac{\frac{x}{2}}{1-\frac{x}{2}}\bigg)+\cos^{-1}\bigg(\frac{-\frac{x}{2}}{1+\frac{x}{2}}-\frac{(-x)}{1+x}\bigg)=\frac{\pi}{2}$

(Above i have used sum of infinite geometric progression )

So we have $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{1-x}-\frac{x^2}{2-x}=\frac{x}{1+x}-\frac{x}{2+x}$

$\displaystyle x=0$ or $\displaystyle \frac{x}{(1-x)(2-x)}=\frac{1}{(1+x)(2+x)}$

So one solution is $x=0$ but I am struck in other real solution.

Now how do I solve it, help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have correctly got

> $\displaystyle x=0$ or $\displaystyle \frac{x}{(1-x)(2-x)}=\frac{1}{(1+x)(2+x)}$

Now,
$$\frac{x}{(1-x)(2-x)}=\frac{1}{(1+x)(2+x)}$$
is equivalent to
$$x(1+x)(2+x)=(1-x)(2-x)$$
i.e.
$$x^3+2x^2+5x-2=0$$
Let $f(x)$ be the LHS.

Then, since $f'(x)=3x^2+4x+5\gt 0$, we see that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing with
$$f(-1)=-6\lt 0\qquad\text{and}\qquad f(1)=6\gt 0$$
So, we see, by the intermediate value theorem, that $f(x)=0$ has exactly one real solution $x=\alpha$ in $(-1,1)$.

Here, note that $\alpha\not=0$ since $f(0)=-2\not=0$.

Therefore, the number of the real solutions of the given equation is $\color{red}2$.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the cubic equation
$$x^3+2x^2+5x-2=0$$ just follow the steps described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_and_hyperbolic_solutions) and obtain the nice
$$x=\frac{2}{3} \left(-1+\sqrt{11} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{64}{11 \sqrt{11}}\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: That's impressive!  Beats my lowly calculator result by a mile!

Comment: @bjcolby15. This is not impressive; just the method to be used if you want to avoid things like https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve%5Bx%5E3%2B2x%5E2%2B5x-2%3D%3D0%2Cx%5D

Comment: Agreed...that WA answer doesn't look nice.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you cross-multiply $$\frac {x}{(1-x)(2-x)} = \frac {1}{(1+x)(2+x)}$$ and multiply everything out and simplify you'd get $$x^3 + 2x^2 + 5x -2 = 0$$

Using a polynomial solver on my calculator, I got the following solutions...

$$x = 0.3444, -1.1722 + 2.1056i, -1.1722 - 2.1056i$$

In the above equation, two of the solutions are imaginary, so the only real solutions are $0$ and $0.3444$.

*(Edited after correcting my original equation)*

Comment: But answer given is 2 real solution

Comment: $x^2+2x+5=0$ doesnot have a real solution as discreminant is $2^2-4\times1\times5<0$

Comment: I was wrong...I forgot to carry over the 2 in the original equation, so my post was incorrect.  I've corrected my post.